# Why use Transpose notation in standart basis vectors unit length equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I had thought I understood everything about orthonormality until I encountered the notation on the source I share below. Why add another step using T? In other sources, it worked just fine without. Could you explain the reason why a human being would spend extra bits and energy to add that?

[image: Screenshot of the equation]

Comment: It matches up with the definition of [matrix multipl8cation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

For two column vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ of the same dimension, we have $$\vec x\cdot \vec y=\vec x^T\vec y$$
based on the definition of matrix multiplication and the dot product. The transpose notation is more preferable for someone who exclusively wants to use matrix operations instead of vector operations like dot products.

Comment: So the result of the dot product of two, let's say, 3x1 matrices is a 3x1 matrice. However, when we transpose the first matrice we get 1x3 matrice and multiply it with 3x1 matrice and get a 1x1 matrice? I feel like my understanding is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Ali the result of the dot product of two $3\times 1$ matrices is a scalar, which is the same as the $1\times 1$ matrice given by the matrix multiplication

Comment: Oh dear universe, I think I was drunk or something yesterday. Thanks!